# Angular resetting search variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Okay so i have the following object:

```
    $scope.search = {};
```

this allows me to search through the following elements:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:search:strict">
```

Now one of the things i can do is to set a variable called `category_id` which then filters the category_id of each item:

```
    $scope.search.category_id = selected.id;
```

However there is a problem. once i try to reset it AKA call `$scope.search.category_id = null`

All result disapear.

So it seem it is searching for categories where `id = null` which is false in every case.

So my question is how do i reset it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the property from the object rather than setting it to null. That will remove it from being listed in the search criteria.

```
delete $scope.search.category_id
```

You can see how this is different from setting it to `null` below

```
var a = { hello: 5 }
console.log(a, Object.keys(a)) // Object {hello: 5} ['hello']

a.hello = null
console.log(a, Object.keys(a)) // Object {hello: null} ['hello']

delete a.hello
console.log(a, Object.keys(a)) // Object {} []
```